# How to flatten a structure of embedded Set and Hash

Tags: ruby, recursion

I would like to convert an embedding structure into a flat one.

- An *embedding structure* is a set of 0 or more objects, such as: a string or a hash having some string as key and some other embedding structure as value.
- A *flat structure* is a set of arrays or strings.

Here some examples:

```
t(
  Set[]
) # => Set[]

t(
  Set[ 'foo' ]
) # => Set[ ['foo'] ]

t(
  Set[ 'foo0',
       'foo1',
       'foo2' ]
) # => Set[ ['foo0'], ['foo1'], ['foo2'] ]

t(
  Set[ 'foo' => Set[ 'bar' ] ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'bar'] ]

t(
  Set[ 'foo' => Set[ 'bar0', 'bar1', 'bar2' ] ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'bar0'],
  #         ['foo', 'bar1'],
  #         ['foo', 'bar2'] ]

t(
  Set[ {'foo' => Set[ 'bar0', 'bar1', 'bar2' ]},
       {'FOO' => Set[ 'BAR0', 'BAR1', 'BAR2' ]} ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'bar0'],
  #         ['foo', 'bar1'],
  #         ['foo', 'bar2'],
  #         ['FOO', 'BAR0'],
  #         ['FOO', 'BAR1'],
  #         ['FOO', 'BAR2'] ]

t(
  Set[ {'foo' => Set[ {'FOO' => Set[ 'BAR' ]} ]} ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'FOO', 'BAR'] ]

t(
  Set[ {'foo' => Set[ {'FOO' => Set[ 'BAR' ]} ]},
       'baz' ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'FOO', 'BAR'],
  #         'baz' ]

t(
  Set[ {'foo' => Set[ {'FOO' => Set[ 'BAR0', 'BAR1' ]} ]},
       'baz' ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'FOO', 'BAR0'],
  #         ['foo', 'FOO', 'BAR1'],
  #         ['baz'] ]

t(
  Set[ {'foo' => Set[ {'FOO' => Set[ 'BAR0', {'BAR1' => Set[ {'abc' => Set[ 'def' ]} ]} ]} ]},
       'baz' ]
) # => Set[ ['foo', 'FOO', 'BAR0'],
  #         ['foo', 'FOO', 'BAR1', 'abc', 'def'],
  #         ['baz'] ]
```

I think we should use resistivity to convert the given structure. But I have no idea for an implementation. Please feel free to any example of `t` function.

**Edit:**

In other words, I would like to develop the *embedding structure* into a *flatten structure*.

We can see the *embedding structure* such as an expression with factors. And if we multiply them, the *flatten structure* is returned.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I suggest that instead of referring to general structures and patterns, you focus on one specific example, showing your desired result. Also, I understand what `t(..)` means, as it clearly not a method.

Comment: I tried to clarify the meaning of the examples at the end of the question...

Comment: BTW, in the examples, `t()` is a method. I used the word function, sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is your friend:

```
require 'set'
def t_h(inp, prefix = [])
    if (inp.is_a?(Hash))
        result = []
        inp.each do |k,v|
            pprefix = prefix.dup
            result << t_h(v, pprefix << k)
        end
        return result.flatten(1)
    elsif (inp.is_a?(Set))
        result = []
        inp.each do |el|
            result << t_h(el, prefix)
        end
        return result.flatten(1)
    else
        pprefix = prefix.dup
        return [ pprefix << inp ]
    end
end

def t(inp)
    Set.new(t_h(inp))
end

# examples
t(Set[ 'foo' => Set[ 'bar' ] ])
t(Set[ 'foo' => Set[ 'bar0', 'bar1', 'bar2' ] ])
t(
  Set[ {'foo' => Set[ 'bar0', 'bar1', 'bar2' ]},
       {'FOO' => Set[ 'BAR0', 'BAR1', 'BAR2' ]} ]
)
```

Code is far from optimal, but you get the idea.

Comment: Gorgeous! Thanks a lot. For me it already production ready! Your Ruby is far better than mine!

Comment: np. production ready or not... i think the idea of how to do this is more important than the implementation. you had he right idea from the moment you asked the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version for your `t` method:

```
def t obj
    raise TypeError, "Expecting Hash, Set or Array objects." unless obj.is_a?(Set) || obj.is_a?(Array) || obj.is_a?(Hash)
    recursive = Proc.new do |item|
        case item
        when Set, Hash
            recursive.call( item.to_a )
        when Array
            item.map {|i| recursive.call(i) }
        else
            item
        end
    end
    recursive.call(obj).flatten
end
```

It's pretty straight forward, but I don't like it all that much... I hope to think of a better one later on.

Comment: sort of flattens everything.

Comment: @Mircea - Wasn't that the idea?

Comment: sort of. look at the examples above.

Comment: Thank you. Your version is pretty much the same as my examples. Really appreciate you help.